# Как средствами javascript загрузить фотографию вконтакте в альбом?

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, post

Желательно именно на `javascript`, а не на `php`. Альбом, в который необходимо загрузить фотографии я создаю а вот фотографии не загружаются.
Т.е. там, вконтакте, загрузка фотографий делится на 3 этапа.

1. Получение адреса сервера для загрузки фотографий,я его получаю.
2. Загрузка фотографий на сервер - не получается.
3. Сохранение фотографии в альбом, сделал только добавление фотографий на стену пользователя.
   Много у кого реализовано (различные фотостатусы), у всех практически нa `php`.
   Там дело идёт с `POST`-запросом.

Comment: а какие-то ошибки выдает? предполагаю, что вы сталкиваетесь с CORS (https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Answer (score 2):

POST запрос и загрузка файлов реализуется и средствами JavaScript. Я искал решения для jQuery. Люди [советуют](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) использовать один из готовых плагинов, напр. [jQuery Form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#code-samples).